# Replace external JSONP with local json in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm going to store a json-file on same server as this Angular-app, and wonder how I can change this code to read my locally stored json-file:

```
ergastAPI.getDrivers = function() {
  return $http({
    method: 'JSONP', 
    url: 'http://somedomain.com/datafile.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  });
}
```

My Json-file will be stored at http:// mysite.com/app/js/datafile.json, while rest of the app will be stored in its parent folder, app.

Do I have to change the method to something else than jsonp?

Answer (score 1):

if it's the same domain, you can just use just $http.get

```
ergastAPI.getDrivers = function() {
  return $http.get('app/js/datafile.json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd change the method to GET and I think you'll have to change the responseType to 'JSON' or something similar. (I'm on my phone right now so you'll have to excuse my brevity)